# making a map in which the value type is an abstract class in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `element` and a child class `elasticFrame` :

```
class element
{
public:
    virtual Matrix getStiffness() = 0;
protected:
    Matrix K;
};


class elasticFrame3d:public element
{
public:
    elasticFrame3d(double E, double G);
    virtual Matrix getStiffness();
virtual Matrix getTransform();
private:
    double E, G;
};
```

what I want is to make a map like this:

```
map<int, element> elementMap;
```

but when I get this error:

```
error C2259: 'element' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

is it even possible to do this? if yes how?

Comment: Wrap it in a `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @0x499602D2 why not just a `std::unique_ptr`? That should be the default, unless sharing ownership is explicitly required.

Comment: would you please explain more?

Comment: Even if you wrapped it in a smart pointer (which would avoid the initial instantiation error), how would the compiler handle something like this: `(*elementMap)[new_key]`? If `new_key` does not currently exist in the map, wouldn't it have to construct a value of value_type element and also give a compiler error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to create a value of type `element` as it has abstract function. If you want to store objects of a type derived from `element`, you'll need to store a suitable pointer or reference to these objects. You can, e.g., use `std::unique_ptr<element>` or `std::shared_ptr<element>` (you need to include `#include <memory>`) and allocate the concrete objects in a suitable memory area.

That is, you would use something like this:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<element>> elementMap;
elementMap[17] = std::unique_ptr<element>(new elasticFrame3D(3.14, 2.71));
```

BTW, you are using an unusal naming convention: when using CamelCase types are normally written with a capital letter and objects using a lowercase initial letter.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick response,would you please explain more I don't understand what do you mean by _std::unique_ptr<element>_

Comment: One reason why you cannot do this: If you were accessing your map using the `[]` operator, and supplied a key that is not currently in the map, std::map will attempt to construct a value of value_type referenced by that key. As key_type is abstract, this cannot work.

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar: I don't understand what you mean? The key tpye happens to be `int`. When an object doesn't exist, a default constructed `std::unique_ptr<element>` will be created. Well, yes, a `std::unique_ptr<element>` may not point at anything...

Comment: AH, I thought you meant to wrap the std::map in a unique ptr and not the value_type. DERP. My statement was merely referring to why you cannot do the ORIGINAL approach. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Alexander1991: `std::unique_ptr<T>` is a class template defined by the standard C++ library (it is declared in `<memory>`). It hold a pointer to an object of type `T` and it `delete`s the pointer when it destroyed itself. In theory, you could just store `element*` in your map but when doing so you are setting yourself up for a memory leak. By using a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<T>`. Since it more lightweight and modelling strict ownership, I think `std::unique_ptr<element>` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers!

```
Declaration:
map<int, element*> elementMap;
```

Use:

```
elasticFrame3d thing = elasticFrame3d(1,1);
elementMap[0] = &thing;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. For this to be a helpful answer, please expand it with more explanation.